# Left and Right Hand Riemann Sum

Tags: calculus, integration

I am stuck at **Example** of this [Calculus Wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Calculus/Definite_integral#Left_and_Right_Handed_Riemann_Sums). In this example we will calculate the area under the curve given by the graph of $f(x)=x$ for $x$ between $[0,1]$. First we divide the interval into $n$ sub-intervals of equal width. So each sub-interval has width $\Delta x = \frac{1}{n}$. Wikipedia says Right Hand Riemann sum will be equal to:

$$x_i^* = 0 + i\,\Delta x = \frac in $$

I can't comprehend how zero is the first element in calculation using Right Hand Riemann Sum (RHRS). e.g. take this integral $$\int_0^1 x\,dx$$

Let us say I divide this into 4 equal sub-intervals, hence $\Delta x = \frac14$ and 4 sub-intervals will be $$[0,\frac14], [\frac14,\frac24],[\frac24,\frac34], [\frac34,\frac44]$$

Hence Left-Hand Riemann Sum (LHRS) meaning taking left points and RHRS means taking right points. That means $$LHRS = \frac14 [0 + \frac14 + \frac24 + \frac34]$$
$$RHRS = \frac14 [\frac14 + \frac24 + \frac34 + \frac44]$$

That means zero is coming as first element in LHRS but not in RHRS, then how come Wikipedia shows zero in RHRS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct in your intuition, you've just made a mistake in the indexing. If you look at the link, it says that $i=1,2,...,n$. So, $i$ starts from $1$, not $0$. That means that your first interval is $x_1^*=\Delta x$, not $x_0^*=0$.

Comment: I am sorry, I just did not get your point. Yes, Wikipedia says **i** starts from **1** and that is the reason I can't understand. If **i** starts from **1** then how come zero is the first element in RHRS, it should be **1** . or I don't understand it at all ?

Comment: @Arnuld Wikipedia is NOT saying that zero is the first element in the RHSR. It's saying the first element in the RHSR is $\Delta x$. If you look at the formula they gave, $x_i^*=0+i\Delta x$, it NEVER gives back $x_i^*=0$.

Comment: @Arnuld You're perfectly correct that zero is not the first element in the RHSR, and nowhere in the wikipedia page does it *claim* zero is the first element in the RHSR. It consistently says the first element in the RHSR is $(\Delta x)^2$

Comment: I got it now. Thanks